# Why does this Haskell TCP server generate an `invalid argument` error with accept?

Tags: haskell, tcp

When running this TCP server, using [Network.Simple.TCP](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/network-simple-0.4.5/docs/Network-Simple-TCP.html)'s `serve` command, I get an invalid argument from `accept`; this happens both in this example, which is whittled down and extracted slightly from a program that instead receives protobuf messages (rather than text messages) over TCP. The error, however, is the same:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
{- stack script --nix --resolver lts-14.27
  --nix-packages zlib
  --no-nix-pure
  --package bytestring
  --package classy-prelude
  --package conduit
  --package exceptions
  --package mtl
  --package network
  --package network-simple
  --package stm
  --package stm-conduit
  --package text
  --package unliftio
  --ghc-options -Wall
-}
{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude #-}

{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes                  #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables         #-}

module Main where

import           ClassyPrelude                    hiding (hClose)
import           Conduit
import           Control.Concurrent.STM.TBQueue   (TBQueue, writeTBQueue)
import           Control.Monad.Catch              (MonadMask)
import           Control.Monad.Writer
import           Data.Bits                        (shiftR, (.&.))
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8            as B
import           Data.Conduit.Async               (gatherFrom)
import qualified Data.Conduit.List                as CL
import           Data.Function                    ((&))
import qualified Data.Text                        as T
import           GHC.IO.Handle                    (Handle, hClose)
import qualified Network.Simple.TCP               as TCP
import qualified Network.Socket                   as NS
import           UnliftIO.Concurrent              (ThreadId, forkIO, threadDelay)

type Error = [String]
type Result r = Writer Error r

runResult :: Result r -> (r, Error)
runResult = runWriter

getPort :: NS.ServiceName
getPort = "29876"

waitForever :: IO ()
waitForever = do
  threadDelay 10000
  waitForever

-- | This signature is meant to simulate the same function from the proto-lens library,
-- | but without dealing with protobus for binary data.
decodeMessageDelimitedH :: Handle -> IO (Either String String)
decodeMessageDelimitedH h = do
    sOut <- B.hGetLine h
    pure $ Right $ B.unpack sOut

protoServe :: forall m. (MonadMask m, MonadResource m, MonadUnliftIO m) =>
     (String -> Result [String])
  -> ConduitT () [String] m ()
protoServe fromProto = start .| mapMC logFilterRead
  .| CL.catMaybes .| mapMC msgToRecs
  where
    port = trace "getting protobuf port" getPort
    start = do
      let enQserver = serveTBQ (TCP.HostIPv4) port (decodeProto . fst)
      gatherFrom 10000 enQserver
    decodeProto :: NS.Socket -> m (Either String String)
    decodeProto sock = bracket
      connHandleIO
      (liftIO . hClose)
      (liftIO . decodeMessageDelimitedH)
      where
        connHandleIO :: m Handle
        connHandleIO = liftIO $ sockToHandle sock
    logFilterRead :: Either String String -> m (Maybe String)
    logFilterRead pEi = case pEi of
      Right p -> pure $ Just p
      Left err -> trace err $ pure Nothing
    msgToRecs :: String -> m [String]
    msgToRecs p = case runResult $ fromProto p of
      (rs, rErr) -> do
        when (not $ null rErr) $ pure $ trace (intercalate "\n" rErr) ()
        pure $ trace "completed msgToRecs" rs

-- | The handle only needs a read-view of the socket.  Note that a TBQeueue is
-- | mutable but has STM's runtime safety checks in place.
sockToHandle :: NS.Socket -> IO Handle
sockToHandle sock = NS.socketToHandle sock ReadMode

-- | Based on serve and listen from Network.Simple.TCP
-- | Unlike `serve`, which never returns, `serveTBQ` immediately returns
-- | a `TBQueue` of results.
serveTBQ :: forall a m. (MonadMask m, MonadUnliftIO m)
  => TCP.HostPreference -- ^ Host to bind.
  -> NS.ServiceName -- ^ Server service port name or number to bind.
  -> ((NS.Socket, NS.SockAddr) -> m a)
  -- ^ Computation to run in a different thread once an incoming connection is
  -- accepted. Takes the connection socket and remote end address.
  -> TBQueue a -- ^ enqueue computation results to this queue
  -> m ()
  -- ^ Returns a FIFO (queue) of results from concurrent requests
serveTBQ hp port rFun tbq = do
    _ <- async $ withRunInIO $ \run -> TCP.serve hp port $ \(lsock, _) -> do
      run $ void $ acceptTBQ lsock rFun tbq
    putStrLn $ T.pack "exiting serveTBQ"

-- | Based on acceptFork from Network.Simple.TCP.
acceptTBQ :: forall a m.
  MonadUnliftIO m
  => NS.Socket -- ^ Listening and bound socket.
  -> ((NS.Socket, NS.SockAddr) -> m a)
  -- ^ Computation to run in a different thread once an incoming connection is
  -- accepted. Takes the connection socket and remote end address.
  -> TBQueue a
  -> m ThreadId
acceptTBQ lsock rFun tbq = mask $ \restore -> do
  (csock, addr) <- trace ("running restore-accept on lsock: " <> (show lsock)) $ restore (liftIO $ NS.accept lsock)
  onException (forkIO $ finally
    (restore $ do
      rVal <- trace "retrieved rVal in finally-restore" rFun (csock, addr)
      atomically $ writeTBQueue tbq rVal)
    (TCP.closeSock csock))
    (TCP.closeSock csock)

retryForever :: forall m a. MonadUnliftIO m => m a -> m a
retryForever prog = catchAny prog progRetry
  where
    progRetry :: SomeException -> m a
    progRetry ex = do
      putStrLn $ pack $ show ex
      threadDelay 4000000
      retryForever prog

-- | Safer interface to sinkNull
sinkUnits :: MonadResource m => ConduitT () Void m ()
sinkUnits = sinkNull

main :: IO ()
main = retryForever $ do
  putStrLn $ T.pack "starting tcp server"
  let myProtoServe = protoServe (pure . words)
  myProtoServe .| mapMC (putStrLn . T.pack . intercalate "_") .| sinkUnits & runConduitRes
  putStrLn $ T.pack "tcp server exited"
  waitForever
```

When running the above server and executing a `netcat` command feeding in some text over TCP, e.g. `netcat 127.0.0.1 29876 < .bashrc` (substitute `.bashrc` with any text file), I see output like the following:

```
starting tcp server
exiting serveTBQ
getting protobuf port
tcp server exited
running restore-accept on lsock: <socket: 16>
tcpConduitServer-exe: Network.Socket.accept: invalid argument (Invalid argument)
```

I'm not sure what would cause this behavior, though I'm not experience with TCP. Since I'm using `serve` rather than writing my own TCP logic, I'm a bit surprised at receiving a TCP error.

Here is a repository containing the script (as well as the non-script version):
https://github.com/bbarker/tcpConduitServer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you call `NS.accept` on a socket connected to the client.

As documented at [Network.Simple.TCP.serve](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/network-simple-0.4.5/docs/Network-Simple-TCP.html#v:serve), `TCP.serve` accepts a socket and invokes its third argument by passing the accepted socket in a different thread. `lsock` in `serveTBQ` is a socket connected to the client, not a server socket to accept a new connection.

When you write a TCP server, you need to 1) create a socket, 2) bind it to an address and a port, 3) listen it, then 4) accept it. `TCP.serve` does all these tasks for you, so all you need to do is to read/write on a socket `TCP.serve` provides to your callback function.

Comment: Ah, yes, can't believe I missed that - wrote the code a few months ago and assumed that aspect was relatively solid. I guess this is a case where newtyping sockets (client vs server listener socket) might be a good idea as part of the socket API.